# Why writing speed is not high as reading speed in usb 3?

Tags: usb, usb-drive, benchmarks

I have attached the `benchmark` test finding for my new computer. The test is for `USB 3`, and in the result the writing speed is only `23.8 Mb/s` but the reading speed is ok as expected for usb 3. Can any one please give me a solution how to solve the problem I am facing with my new computer. I am using `HP 250 G1 Notebook PC`. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: It is becuase flash drive writing speed is much lower than reading speed. It is not related to USB or Ubuntu at all.

Comment: But in usb 3 the writing speed also should be high, is'n it?

Comment: 23.8 MB/s *is* high. USB 2.0 pendrives give, what, 4-8 MB/s?

Comment: This is the result for usb 2...  http://postimg.org/image/yg039h273/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two speeds to take into account: one is the bus' speed and the other one is the drive's speed; the lowest of the two is a bottleneck and sets the maximum overall speed you're going to get.

USB 3.0 on his own caps at 4.8 Gbps (600 MB/s), but reasonably only SSDs might reach that cap; commercial (even not cheap) USB flash drives are usually *way* slower; USB hard drives, IME, can reach around 80 MB/s when writing sequentially.

So the fact that a drive is USB 3.0 compatible doesn't mean that its speed will match USB 3.0's specifications, because that depends on the drive itself; the only thing you can safely assume from the fact that a drive is USB 3.0 compatible is just that, when plugged into a USB 3.0 port, in case the drive itself can reach a speed higher than 480 Mbps (which is something USB 3.0 hard drives, IME, usually do), it will not be bottlenecked by the bus; for a USB flash drive, speed-wise, IME, USB 2.0 is plenty already, because they are usually terribly slow compared to USB hard drives.